# Serva PXE boot - servapenet cannot find/run remote setup.exe error

Tags: windows

I'm having an error in Serva PXE boot, The moment I connect to the computer where windows 10 ReviOS is hosted in serva. I already extracted the .iso file. Is the error causes because of no setup.exe on the first path directory of the extracted files. But inside the sources folder there is setup.exe.

Inside the .iso file:

[image: Screenshot upon extracting the iso]

Inside the sources folder:

[image: Inside the sources folder]

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows asset does not look like a regular Windows Install ISO (Retail, MSDN, etc.)
and the Setup.exe in the root directory is missing; that's what `ServaPENet` is looking for and fails.